# Laravel, как подставить переменную во все url проекта

Tags: php, laravel, маршрутизатор, laravel-8

Есть переменная, задача подставить ее во все url проекта.
Немного подробнее: переменная session('locale') возвращает язык сайта 'ru' или другой. Не могу понять как подставить переменную в маршруты по умолчанию.

Пока дошел до того, что бы в шаблоне использовать линки типа `<a href="{{session('locale')}}/page">Page</a>`, но не хочется нагромождать html-шаблон, хочется решить задачу на начале роутинга так, что бы все ссылки /page по умолчанию шли с маршрутом session('locale'), те `ru/page`

Сейчас роутинг выглядит так:

```
Route::group(
    [
        // Get Prefix Language ['en', 'ru']
        'prefix' => Localization::language(),
        'middleware' => 'language',
    ],
    function (){

        // Main Page
        Route::get('/', function () {
            return view('home.index');
        });

        // Language Page
        Route::get('/language', function () {
            return view('home.language');
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Задаете язык по-умолчанию и помещаете в сессию посетителя. Затем используете это вместо роутинга-по-умолчанию, чтобы было проще. А для Blade шаблонов определите [свое слово](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#extending-blade) и подставляйте если session('locale') слишком длинное.

Comment: Я уже помещаю в сессию, как описано в задаче. Так же в задаче стоит указывать locale в роуте, а не в шаблоне.

Comment: просто каждому маршруту присвойте имя. и при вызове route('имя маршрута') он автоматом будет добавлять префикс